# Equivalent statement of the Wiener-Tauberian theorem?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I would like to know why we have the equivalence between the following three statements of the **Wiener-Tauberian theorem**:

**version 1:** If $I$ is a closed ideal in $L^1(\mathbb R)$, such that the set $hull(I)=\{\varphi: L^1(\mathbb R)\to \mathbb C \, \mbox{homomorphism}: \varphi(x) = 0\, \forall x\in I\}=\emptyset \, $,  then: $I=L^1(\mathbb R)$.

**version 2:** Every proper closed ideal in $L^1(\mathbb R)$ is contained in a maximal ideal.

**version 3:** If $f\in L^1(\mathbb R)$, such that its Fourier transform $\hat f$ is a nowhere vanishing function on $\mathbb R$, then the closed ideal generated by f is whole of $L^1(\mathbb R)$, i.e., $\overline{span}\{f_{\tau},\,  \tau \in \mathbb R\}= L^1(\mathbb R)$.

Thank you in advance

Comment: can you post the sources for each of these three statements?

Comment: @John, You can find them in every article that deals with the Wiener-Tauberian theorem